# error: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, cocoapods

My flutter project is not working on ios devices getting.
i have tried below the command `sudo gem install cocoapods` .

**flutter run:**

```
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
To install:
  sudo gem install cocoapods
  pod setup



Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                                   
Xcode build done.                                            4.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    error: /Users/sukhjinder/StudioWorkspace/shrutiFlutterProjects/myapp/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target
    Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')
   
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
```

Comment: Are you opening .xcproject or .xcworkspace file ??

Comment: .xcworkspace file. Thanks but it got solved by my senior developer. Still dunno I how it got solved.

Comment: he might have change the Workspace build settings -> In Xcode -> Go to File section -> workspace settings -> build System -> chane it to `Legacy Build System`

Comment: Since flutter is quite new, it makes less sense to switch to `Legacy Build System`.

Comment: It worked for me only after reinstalling the Flutter SDK

Answer (score 50):

Open "Terminal" and navigate to your flutter project.
Then navigate inside "ios" folder by `cd ios` and run `pod install`.

For me the problem was that pods weren't installed.

Comment: I ran `pod install` and got to this error.

Answer (score 29):

Open the terminal, navigate to the project and type

```
rm ios/Podfile
```

After that build the project with

```
flutter build ios
```

It solved the problem for me.

Comment: Curios enough, this solution worked for me, but only if I hit flutter run on Terminal. If I try to run the project using Android Studio (green arrow) the error persists. Just a note.

Answer (score 10):

try to install pod

```
cd ios

pod install
```

if it is not working, following this way

navigate **ios/Podfile** file and uncomment `platform :ios, '9.0'`(remove #)

Comment: Find the ios folder in your project and run **pod install**

Comment: i try this step but i got a this types of error:-  `Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists' for class File.`

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I have added 2 files in `ios/Flutter` Folder

**1 Debug.xcconfig**

```
 #include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
 #include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

**2 Release.xcconfig**

```
  #include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
  #include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

Answer (score 6):

Flutter/Release.xcconfig

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"   

#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig"  

#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the terminal, navigate to the project by typing:

   `cd your_file_path`
2. After that navigate to the iOS folder by typing:

   `cd ios`
3. Finally, fix your problem by implementing the missing podfile by typing:

   `pod init`
4. Then, open the newly created podfile, follow instructions in the file (which tell you to remove a comment on the second line of the file).
5. Close your Flutter project, and reopen it.
6. Run your project again.

Answer (score 3):

In my case simply:

```
   cd /[path_to_project_directory]/ios/
```

then

```
   pod update
```

fixed it

Answer (score 2):

**100% works** Easy step:

1. open iso/flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1
2. Remove below line
   #include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"

Note it should have this line  alone #include "Generated.xcconfig"

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the solutions above including completely recreating my ios folder. What finallly worked was uncommenting the `platform :ios` line in the ios/Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
```

to this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and none of the given solutions worked for me.

What has worked for me:

- Delete your podfile (make sure to backup it).
- Now one new podfile will be generated or try `pod init` command.
- Now rerun your project it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I fixed this with the following steps

1. new another flutter project that can ios app
2. copy the missing files [Debug.xcconfig, Release.xcconfig] in the ./ios/Flutter folder to the error project in the same directory.
3. Run, it works

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I refactored my project to move the main folder. What I did to get around it was the following in Xcode's Workspace Settings:

- Switch to the `Legacy Build System` (as explained by @Sumeet Jain in the comments).
- Perform a build, which should work.
- Switch back to `New Build System (Default)`.
- Run the build again.

This should work now, as I think it must have done a repair in the workplace settings.

FYI, the Workspace build settings can be found in the Xcode File menu: `File/Workspace Settings'. Then look under the 'Shared WorkSpace' section in the dialog for the 'Build System' dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

What helped in my case is described here https://fluttercorner.com/cdn-trunk-url-couldnt-be-downloaded-https-cdn-cocoapods-org-cocoapods-version-yml-response-403/

*Somehow Cloudflare detects CocoaPods traffic as a DDoS attack and that’s why this error occurs It is solved now, But In case You Are still facing this error then follow the below steps.
Just need to bypass the CDN By running this command. First of all, remove the trunk pod by running this command.*

```
pod repo remove trunk
```

And now, Open your Podfile and add this line in the beginning

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

And then

```
pod deintegrate
```

Now, install pods by running this command.

```
pod install
```